# Registered depth image from Kinect using openni is all zeros (Indigo)

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to pull point/depth cloud data off of a Kinect on a turtlebot, and I'm having problems.  I start the turtlebot and openni with the standard commands (in different terminals):

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

and open up rviz on my control workstation.  So far, so good - everything starts without errors, and I can plot a pointcloud using the raw depth data.  Unfortunately, what I actually need is the registered depth data.  This isn't available unless I set depth_registration:=true (either using the reconfigure tool or by restarting openni).  If I do this, the registered depth data does show up, but the depth image is all zeros and the pointclouds are full of NaNs.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a 32-bit netbook, and using ROS Indigo (installed from PPA, except for the rocon, kobuki and turtlebot packages, which I compiled).

I know this is not a new problem (see http://answers.ros.org/question/53706/registered-depth-image-is-black/), but all the other posts I've been able to find were from a year ago, with old versions of Ubuntu/ROS, and it seems like the issue was eventually resolved by software updates... at least until now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197244/registered-depth-image-from-kinect-using-openni-is-all-zeros-(indigo)/) by [davidjoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20769/davidjoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should try freenect, it worked for me.

```
 roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch
```

If the error was resolved, how did you do it? Please post.

---

Originally posted by [Loneflyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24028/loneflyer/) with karma: 96 on 2015-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0